# Django user token is not getting authenticated by the user by which it is created

Tags: python, django, django-views, token

i Create a views function to set the user.is_active to true with the help of the link to activate the user account in django

The link contains the uidb64 and token

i genrate the token while signup and send that link by email by that is not getting authanticated with the user

here is the link sending function

```
def register(request):
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUser(data= request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        username = request.POST['email']

        if (email) and (first_name) and (last_name) and (phone_number) and (password) and (password1) and (username):
            try:    
                user = Account.objects.get(username = username)
                error = 'user with this email already exists'
                return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
            except Account.DoesNotExist:
                if password == password1:
                    user = Account.objects.create_user(email= email,first_name= first_name,last_name= last_name,password= password, username=username)
                    user.phone_number = phone_number    
                    # user activation
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    email_subject = 'Activate your account'
                    message = render_to_string('account/email.html',{'user': user , 'domain':current_site, 'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)) , 
                    'token':default_token_generator.make_token(user)
                    })
                    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                    to_email = email
                    send_email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message , to=[email])
                    send_email.send()
                    user.save()
                    print(user)
                else:
                    error = "Passwords didn't match"
                    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
        else:
            error = 'Fill the form correctly'
            return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html',context)
```

here is code where i check the token

```
def activate(request, uidb64 ,token):

    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = Account._default_manager.get(pk = uid)
    except (TypeError,ValueError,OverflowError,Account.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    print(default_token_generator.check_token(user, token))
    # This is retruning false
    if user is not None:
        if default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            user.email = 'gnai'
            user.save()
            print(user)
            print('thosi')
            print(user.email)
            return render(request , 'core/base.html')
        else:
            print(',a')
```

The problem in this that
print(default_token_generator.check_token(user, token))
this is returning the False

here is how i create teh user

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,first_name, last_name, username, email , password =None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email Address is not present.')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is not present')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,first_name, last_name, username, email , password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password = password,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user


# Create your models here.
class  Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50 , unique=True)
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length = 100 , unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField( max_length=50)

# required fields for 
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name' ,'last_name']
    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm , obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self , add_label):
        return True
```

if any extra information is needed then just comment below
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
as we know that the token also uses the time to genrate the token
then i my case it uses the last login time to genrate the token
then
now for the solution
i move the user.save before the token token get genrated

now the new code is this

```
def register(request):
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUser(data= request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        username = request.POST['email']

        if (email) and (first_name) and (last_name) and (phone_number) and (password) and (password1) and (username):
            try:    
                user = Account.objects.get(username = username)
                error = 'user with this email already exists'
                return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
            except Account.DoesNotExist:
                if password == password1:
                    user = Account.objects.create_user(email= email,first_name= first_name,last_name= last_name,password= password, username=username)
                    user.phone_number = phone_number    
                    user.save()
                    token =default_token_generator.make_token(user)
                    print(user)
                    print(token)
                    # user activation
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    email_subject = 'Activate your account'
                    message = render_to_string('account/email.html',{'user': user , 'domain':current_site, 'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)) , 
                    'token':token,
                    })
                    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                    to_email = email
                    send_email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message , to=[email])
                    send_email.send()
                    print(user)
                    print(token)
                else:
                    error = "Passwords didn't match"
                    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
        else:
            error = 'Fill the form correctly'
            return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'error':error})
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html',context)
```